# set / get input / output parameters of a Camunda user task using Java API

Tags: java, workflow, bpmn, business-process-management, camunda

I have simple workflow:

```
[start_workflow] -> [user_task] -> 
-> [exclusive_gateway] -> (two routes see below) -> [end_workflow]
```

The [exclusive_gateway] has two outgoing routes:

```
1.) ${if user_task output paramterer == null} -> [NULL_service_task] -> [end_workflow]

2.) ${if user_task output paramterer != null} -> [NOT_null_service_task] -> [end_workflow]
```

In Camunda Modeler, I've added an output parameter (named out) to the [user_task].

Q:
How do I set thet output parameter through Java API **before** completing the task via:

```
taskService.complete(taskId);
```

On the [exclusive_gateway] arrows, I've set this:

```
Condition type = expression
Expression = ${out != null}
```

**But there's more**:

If I delete the output parameter of the [user_task] and set a runtimeService variable before completing the task:

```
runtimeService.setVariable(processInstanceId, "out", name);
```

The [exclusive_gateway] does handle the parameter, and routes the flow as expected.
Without deleting the output parameter of the [user_task] it seems like:
1. it is never set (so == null)
2. this null value overwrites the value set by

```
runtimeService.setVariable(processInstanceId, "out", name);
```

So can I set a task's output parameter via Java API or I can only use process variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are looking for

```
taskService.complete(<taskId>, Variables.putValue("out", <name>);
```

the communication between task and gateway (forwarding of the value) happens through setting the process-variable "out" on complete.

for more info, check the [javadoc](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.6/org/camunda/bpm/engine/TaskService.html#complete(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map)).